why does it seem my variable is updating with the new data after it saves to the file? React and NWJS
I'm working on a note-taking app using React and NWJS, where notes are saved to a separate file (save.json). The app fetches initial data from this file using a useEffect hook, handles input changes with handleChange, and saves data to the file with saveFile.
The issue I'm facing is that when I click the save button, it only saves the initial empty array, not the updated fullData containing new notes. However, after the initial save, subsequent clicks correctly save the updated data.
const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);

const [noteData, setNoteData] = useState({
    id: Date.now(),
    name: '',
    note: '',
    category: ''
});

// Fetch initial data from file
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await fs.promises.readFile('./save.json', 'utf8');
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            setFullData(jsonData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNoteData(prevData => ({ ...prevData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    console.log(noteData);
};

const saveFile = async () => {
    try {
        const stringData = JSON.stringify(fullData);
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./save.json', stringData);
        console.log('Saved data:', fullData);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

i tried moving some of the functions into the app.js component thinking it would help with the data transfer, because teh initial useEffect that fetches from the file is on app.js. ive tried using a timeout for the saveFile function to make sure fullData was updated before saveFile runs

It seems your code has a logical issue now. For example, when you update noteData in handleChange, you need to add the updated noteData into fullData so that you can save updated fullData containing new notes.
I updated your code like this :
const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);

const [noteData, setNoteData] = useState({
    id: Date.now(),
    name: '',
    note: '',
    category: ''
});

const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNoteData(prevData => ({ ...prevData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    console.log(noteData);
};

const saveFile = async () => {
    try {
        const stringData = JSON.stringify(fullData);
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./save.json', stringData);
        console.log('Saved data:', fullData);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

// Add updated noteData into fullData
useEffect(() => {
    setFullData(prevData => [...prevData, noteData]);
}, [noteData]);


// Fetch initial data from file
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await fs.promises.readFile('./save.json', 'utf8');
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            setFullData(jsonData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);


when i add that useEffect it saves every keystroke as a new entry
